# Why isn't gdb working for me

Tags: ros, gdb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### Background

I am currently trying to build an autonomous drone using *ROS* on my *Rapsberry Pi* which is running an *Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS*. Solving the Computer Vision problem of recognising red circles as of now.

### Specific Problem

I am constantly getting the error I get in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42145106/opencv-error-assertion-failed-a-size-width-len) question. To help me solve this, I have decided to use gdb. However, the command `rosrun --prefix 'gdb run --args' zlab_drone vdstab` does not seem to be working for me. `zlab_drone` is the name of the package and `vdstab` is the name of the executable I am trying to run. Since this is inside a ROS environment, I have grabbed the syntax from [here](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB), and used the suggestions in #q222530.

When I invoke this command, even with `tui`, I get a `SIGSEGV` and when I invoke `list` inside `gdb` itself, the program does not stay at a particular point and keeps listing a different line till it is out of range. This is quite a weird issue.

I managed to make it work without this issue earlier by using a different command, I reckon. I just cannot remember how I made it work last time.

### UPDATES

So, I try to run my program with the command:

```
rosrun --prefix 'gdb run --args' zlab_drone vdstab
```

and I get:

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11-0ubuntu1) 7.11
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "arm-linux-gnueabihf".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from /home/sharan/catkin_ws/devel/lib/zlab_drone/vdstab...done.
(gdb)
```

Which is all okay till now. Now I run `start`, at which point I get:

```
(gdb) start 
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x1e436: file /home/sharan/catkin_ws/src/zlab_drone/src/vidStab.cpp, line 136.
Starting program: /home/sharan/catkin_ws/devel/lib/zlab_drone/vdstab 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x76fd9822 in ?? () from /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
(gdb)
```

Which is a bit weird. To see where the segmentation fault is, I try to `list`. The first time I get this:

```
(gdb) list 
122 //  warpAffine(cv_ptr->image, orig_warped, invTrans.rowRange(0,2), 
123 //          Size());
124     
125     // Publishing (Only uncomment, if you're sure nothing is broken
126     // in this section)
127     /*
128     cv_ptr->image = orig_warped; 
129     image_pub_.publish(cv_ptr->toImageMsg());   
130     */
131     }
(gdb)
```

The second time, I get this:

```
(gdb) list 
132 
133 };
134 
135 int main(int argc, char** argv)
136 {
137   ros::init(argc, argv, "video_stabilizer");
138   Tracker tr;
139   ros::spin();
140   return 0;
141 }
(gdb)
```

Third:

```
(gdb) 
142 
143 
(gdb)
```

Fourth:

```
(gdb) 
Line number 144 out of range; /home/sharan/catkin_ws/src/zlab_drone/src/vidStab.cpp has 143 lines.
(gdb)
```

and finally fifth, and so on and so forth:

```
(gdb) 
Line number 144 out of range; /home/sharan/catkin_ws/src/zlab_drone/src/vidStab.cpp has 143 lines.
(gdb)
```

### When I use Backtrace

```
Reading symbols from /home/sharan/catkin_ws/devel/lib/zlab_drone/vdstab...done.
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x1e436: file /home/sharan/catkin_ws/src/zlab_drone/src/vidStab.cpp, line 136.
Starting program: /home/sharan/catkin_ws/devel/lib/zlab_drone/vdstab 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x76fd9822 in ?? () from /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x76fd9822 in ?? () from /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
#1  0x76fd983a in ?? () from /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
(gdb)
```

What exactly is the problem here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254692/why-isn%27t-gdb-working-for-me/) by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2017-02-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-02-15**:
Seems like your terminal state might be funky. Try running `stty sane` to reset it before you start your node.

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-02-15**:
@ahendrix nope, invoked `stty sane` and restarted the program but I still get the error:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x76fd9822 in ?? () from /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
```

I even restarted the Raspberry Pi.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-15**:
I don't think @ahendrix' comment was meant as a solution to your `SEGFAULT`, but it could've been a way to get `gdb` to behave again.

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-02-15**:
@gvdhoorn Yeah, I got that, but I was just expanding on the fault that I am getting

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-02-15**:
To clarify: running `stty sane` should fix the issue where running `list` in gdb produces unending output, but it won't fix your segfault. The segfault is almost certainly a bug in your code.

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-02-15**:
Yes of course, I get that. But it is obviously buggy, as it should manually go to the start of `main` and then approach the segfault through `step` or `next`.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-02-15**:
It sounds like you're expecting things from gdb that it doesn't do by default. Can you edit your question to include the full text of your debugging session?

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-02-16**:
yeah, I've posted exactly what I get when I open up gdb. The thing is, I didn't get this, last time I ran gdb, where I used specific syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like your program is crashing on startup. There is code that runs before main, and it looks like something in there is crashing.

gdb's `list` command is not my preferred choice for debugging; looking at the backtrace (gdb's `backtrace` command) will show the series of function calls and the final line where your program crashed.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-02-17**:
I have just added what happens when I use `backtrace` instead of list.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-02-17**:
This looks a lot like https://bugs.launchpad.net/gdb/+bug/1576432 ; which suggests that you can get around the issue by connecting gdb to your process after it starts: https://bugs.launchpad.net/gdb/+bug/1576432/comments/4

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-02-17**:
yeah that workaround is the solution to this, it seems like. Either ways, for convenience's sake, I shall use valgrind.

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-02-17**:
okay, it seems like I get a similar error with `valgrind`. Should I take this up somewhere?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-02-18**:
It seems like this is a bug in gdb or Ubuntu's version of gdb, so I recommend that you follow up on the launchpad bug that I linked to.